# Präpositionaladverb "daran" mit Dativ

Tags: dative, pronominal-adverb

Guten Tag,
Welcher Satz is richtig?

> Ich habe mich um ein Praktikum beworben,daran ich teilnehmen muss

oder

> Ich habe mich um ein Praktikum beworben,an dem ich teilnehmen muss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nach der Änderung von *daran* zu [woran](https://www.dwds.de/wb/woran) im ersten Beispiel (und Einfügen eines Leerzeichens nach dem Komma), sind beide Sätze in Ordnung. *Daran* klingt etwas seltsam, wenn es einen Nebensatz einleitet.

Eine andere Möglich ist, *daran* zu behalten, aber einen zweiten Hauptsatz daraus zu machen.

> Ich habe mich um ein Praktikum beworben. Daran muss ich teilnehmen.